# Wordpress ajax not returning the result

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm using the below code for one of my simple work in wordpress plugins.

```
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){

    $j.ajax({
    url:"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:'action=market_place_posting_display&page='+ page1,
    success:function(data){$j('#mine').html(data);}
    });

    });
```

The thing is task is working properly but it's not displaying the echo statment . If i do any insert or delete or what ever operations it's doing. But when i try to print the data through the success message it's not displaying! Could any one can guide me , what's the problem here? If i do the same thing normally without wordpress it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

what are you doing in that "data" part ?? OMG!!! grave mistake!!

you should pass real values in the data or
remove data and encode the url yourself and put it in the url.

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){

    $j.ajax({
    url:"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=market_place_posting_display&page="+ page1,
    type:"POST",

    success:function(data){$j('#mine').html(data);}
    });
```

Comment: even though if i remove the data and put in to the url. The same thing is happening !! But now i made in another way , it's appending the data. But the result is always 0.. What's wrong with this?

Comment: shrinath the first mentioned code itself working like charm! The biggest mistake i made was, the path in the url. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){

$j.ajax({
url:"<?php bloginfo('wpurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
type:"POST",
data:'action=market_place_posting_display&page='+ page1,
success:function(data){$j('#mine').html(data);}
});

});
```

The tag bloginfo('wpurl'); was missing!